# aptitude: symbol lookup error: aptitude: undefined symbol

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, aptitude

When I run the following in my terminal:

```
 aptitude search linux-headers | grep ^i
```

I get the following error:

```
aptitude: symbol lookup error: aptitude: undefined symbol: _ZNK13Configuration10FindVectorB5cxx11EPKc
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce on 14.04. Have you tried updating aptitude with `sudo apt-get install aptitude` ?

Comment: @Musher - i think its already installed since I got the following: aptitude **is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 882 not upgraded.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1503052) it looks like running the following will fix your issue:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude libapt-pkg4.16
```

If you get `unable to locate package libapt-pkg4.16` run this:

```
apt-cache search libapt-pkg | grep 'package management' | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

And replace `libapt-pkg4.16` with whatever output you get from there (for me on 14.04 it's `libapt-pkg4.12`)